# Дождаться ответа от микроконтроллера в теле цикла программы Async-await в C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Отправляю с windows forms C# пакет данных в микроконтроллер, и теперь нужно дождаться ответа о правильности проверки CRC-пакета, думаю запустить еще таймер, например прошло время, ответ не пришел, значит ошибка.  Пока еще мало опыта в работе на C#, сделал так:

```
while(читаем файл по строке и передаем в порт)
{ /*выставляем флаг занятости и висим здесь пока не придет ответ о статусе очистки памяти*/
    DelayBeforeNextOperation = true;
    ResetDelay(true);
    while (DelayBeforeNextOperation == true)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
}//ждать флага что мк свободен или флага ошибки
```

Но это очень не правильно, если флаг не придет программа зависает. Как это правильно делается на Async/await, правильность оформления и т.п. Может кто может поделится пару строками примера?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, где именно этот код вызывается. Постарайтесь добавить чуть больше кода. А так, из вашего описания - если хотите дождаться выполнения какой-то таски - можете воспользоваться `Wait()`, по аналогии с этим ответом https://stackoverflow.com/a/15151444/13123688. Возможно, в вашей задаче подойдёт обычная реализация `async-await`, по аналогии с этим ответом https://stackoverflow.com/a/14178317/13123688. Опять же, это гадание на кофейной гуще - нужно больше кода.

Comment: @Frehzy `Wait()` это шило на мыло, человек спрашивает как от синхронного ожидания избавиться, а вы ему его же и предлагаете. Никаких `Task.Wait()` категорически использовать в асинхронной среде нельзя. В лучшем случае это будет то же зависание формы, в худшем - дедлок.